# Get token with GoogleAuthUtil.getToken after user was signed in with Google+

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-plus, google-oauth

On android app I implemented Google+ signin. All the relevant scopes (Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PLUS_ME, Scopes.PROFILE) are included. As the app needs to access some data on the app engine backend I try to get the token using  GoogleAuthUtil.getToken where scope is  "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me". The problem is that the confirmation is again needed in order for the app to access basic profile info. 
What could be a problem?

Thanks.